# DB2 ARCHIVING OLD DATA TO DB2 ON ANOTHER SERVER

Tags: sql, optimization, db2

i need to archive data from db to db lying a totally different server (DB2). I can do that with the following steps, but the performance is the issue. i have very large amount of data to archive. anyway to do this with optimized archiving performance?

```
/* TEST WITH 1 TABLE */

--1. RETRIEVE IDs AND SAVE IN LIST - [USE LOOP TO PUSH RECORDS BASED ON IDs IN AN ARRAY]
SELECT ID FROM TABLE_1
WHERE CREATED_TIME >= '2013-08-07 10:06:22' AND CREATED_TIME <= '2013-08-07 11:09:43' 
ORDER BY A.ID ASC




--2. DROP INDEXES [TOO SLOW!!!]
ALTER TABLE TABLE_1_ARC DROP PRIMARY KEY




--3. INSERT RECORDS INTO ARC TABLE [STORED PROCEDURE TO INSERT IN ALL TABLES???]
INSERT INTO TABLE_1_ARC
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
WHERE CREATED_TIME >= '2013-08-07 10:06:22' AND CREATED_TIME <= '2013-08-07 11:09:43' 
ORDER BY ID ASC
--LOOPING THROUGH ARRAY FROM STEP 1 WILL BE USED HERE INSTEAD OF WHERE


--4. DELETE ARCHIVED RECORDS FROM OPERATIONAL TABLE [STORED PROCEDURE TO DELETE EVERY FEW RECORDS???]
DELETE FROM TABLE_1 
WHERE CREATED_TIME >= '2013-08-07 10:06:22' AND CREATED_TIME <= '2013-08-07 11:09:43' 
--LOOPING THROUGH ARRAY FROM STEP 1 WILL BE USED HERE INSTEAD OF WHERE



--5. PUT INDEXES BACK [TOO SLOW!!!]
ALTER TABLE TABLE_1_ARC ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

Comment: let me add that database switching in this case is handled by a 3rd party tool

Comment: If the archive tables are in a different database, how are the 2 databases talking - via federation?

Comment: after done reading from the database, a tool is used to switch the database source, and start inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Partition both the source and archive tables by CREATED_TIME. You then will be able to simply detach a partition from the source table and attach it to the archive table, which is almost instantaneous.

Comment: The OP wants the archive on a "totally different server".  Granted you might detach a partition quickly, but don't you have to get it over to the other box before you can attach it to the archive?  Also notice that the timespan shown is just over 63 minutes worth of activity.  We don't know what requirements there might be for choosing cutoff times, or how long the records are being kept for.  This could potentially be a rather large number of partitions.

Comment: i thought of partitions at the beginning, but it rather requires and consumes time. my main problem lies in the delete process. please feel free to even suggest a different approach for archiving large amount of data, efficiently.